# Making an ATM with an EV3

Tags: ev3, programming

I am building an ATM using my LEGO Mindstorms EV3, but I  ran across a problem. The problem is that I want to be able to input the amount of money that I want to get out of the ATM but I can only have a maximum of three touch sensors because I'm using the fourth for the ability to have a key so my siblings don't steal money.

How can I can make an ATM with a maximum of three input to decide how many 20s, 10s, 5s, and 1s I want.

Answer (score 5):

The possible solutions involve realizing that you can multiply the number of possible inputs by implementing long clicks, double clicks, click-and-holds, simultaneous clicks, etc. on the buttons. If I were you, I'd also include a Confirm and maybe a Cancel buttons, but the latter can be substituted by a timeout. You could ease your job if you don't handle the separate bills as individual amounts, but set the requested amount of money and write a function that splits an amount into separate bills (e.g. splitting 58 into 2×20, 1×10, 1×5, 3×1).

With these in mind, have a look at these example button mappings:

Solution #1:

- Button 1: Increase amount by 1
- Button 2: Decrease amount by 1
- Button 3: Confirm

Solution #2:

- Button 1: Increase amount by 1; Long press: increase amount while being held
- Button 2: Decrease amount by 1; Long press: decrease amount while being held
- Button 3: Confirm

Solution #3:

- Button 1: Add 1
- Button 2: Add 5
- Buttons 1+2 simultaneously: Add 10
- Button 3: Add 20
- Buttons 1+2+3 simultaneously: Confirm

Solution #4:

- Button 1: Increase amount by 1
- Button 2: Cancel
- Button 3: Confirm

Of course each approach requires different sub-solutions (as mentioned above, timeouts, detection of long presses and button holds, simultanous presses, etc.). These are up to you, but if you get stuck, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 4):

### Use a Motor as Input

You may be limited by the amount of *touch* sensors you can use, but you have one very useful form of input that you may not be aware of.

EV3 motors have the ability to provide a value based on rotation in degrees. Adjusting the rotation of the motor by hand, you can input very precise numbers quickly. To rotate the motor easily, attach any Technic wheel/gear to the motor using an axle.

---

### Programming a Basic Dial Input

[image]

Create a *unlimited loop block*, this will ensure the current rotation value is always updated. Place a *rotation sensor block*, set to measure in degrees.

[image]

The rotation sensor is very sensitive, it's almost too sensitive because it makes it very difficult to select a number without jumping to another. I recommend you divide the output from the previous block by any number between 10 to 70 to decrease the sensitivity. (10 being the most sensitive).

[image]

The divided numbers are now non-integers, we don't want to be able to take out a fraction of a dollar/pound or whatever currency you are using.

Use the *round block* to round the divided numbers up to a whole number.

[image]

**Optional:** Add a currency prefix. You can use the text block to add a currency prefix, in this case I used the $ sign. EV3 only excepts the $ currency in text inputs. If you would like to use a different currency you would have to render it as an image.

[image]

Display the current amount selected using the display block.

[**Program Overview**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDjXo.png)

---

### Working Example

[image: YouTube Link]

Comment: Nice MinuteBot base you have there. ;)